# Android Studio - Error launching Studio JVM DLL Failed to load

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to launch Android Studio but i get the following error:

> Error launching Studio - Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\server\jvm.dll If you already have a 32-bit JDK Installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computed > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

Installation was without errors. OS is Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to run your Android Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try:

1. set environment variable JAVA_HOME for your JDK as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(your version). (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5 for me)
2. Run Android studio as administrator.
3. remove file .vmoptions from path android studio/bin (
   https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005146240-Error-Launching-Idea-Java-Home-
   )
4. This point really help for me: install it! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170